# Spelling suggestion query (MarkLogic)

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-11

The following code returns an empty sequence:

```
let $dictionaryFileURI := "/dictionary.xml"

let $suggestOptions :=
    <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/spell">
      <distance-threshold>100</distance-threshold>
      <maximum>1</maximum>
    </options>

return spell:suggest-detailed($dictionaryFileURI, 'desaturated', $suggestOptions)
```

The dictionary contains a word entry '*desaturase*', but still '*desaturase*' is not returned as a spelling suggestion. Can someone explain why?

**Note**: I have tried with `distance-threshold` as 1000, but it too didn't work.

Comment: Interestingly, it will suggest `desaturase` if you use `desaturate`.

Comment: @MadsHansen, yes. I did try with 'desaturate', and I got a match. I expected 'desaturated' to match too as the Levenshtein distance is just two when compared to 'desaturase'.